Не добавляются данные в sql таблицу
Всем привет, столкнулся с какой-то непонятной ситуацией. В общем, написал я код(как он выглядит):
with SSHTunnelForwarder(
    ('******', 22),
    ssh_username='root',
    ssh_password='***********',
    remote_bind_address=('localhost', 3306)
) as tunnel:
engine = create_engine(
    f'mysql+pymysql://root:ghghghgh@127.0.0.1:{tunnel.local_bind_port}/asynt')

try:
    with engine.connect() as connection:
        query = text('INSERT INTO popopo (id) values (6);')
        connection.execute(query)
        print("Данные успешно добавлены в таблицу 'popopo'")
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Ошибка при добавлении данных: {str(e)}")

Тут подключение через ssh, как видно, я тут на удаленный сервер подключаюсь, и проблема такого характера: почему-то INSERT INTO не работает вообще, я попытался как-то поменять, но не помогало, но зато работает CREATE TABLE, очень странная ситуация, но может кто знает, почему это не добавляются данные, но создается таблица.
Спасибо, что прочитали, хорошего дня.

А что за функция text()?

@CrazyElf, это с алхимии функция, вот импорты:
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, text  from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder

Ну попробуйте connection.commit() что ли сделать после инсерта. Я не помню тут есть автокоммит или нужно руками. Такие штуки как создание БД автоматом коммитятся, а вот работа с записями уже нет.

@CrazyElf, о реально, спасибо большое, если кто столкнется, то после execute'a надо коммитить, от души
